# is there a direct formula for arctan(2x)?

Tags: trigonometry

I know couple of formulas for trigonometric functions. But I don't know if such formulas exists for inverse trigonometric functions. I don't have a clue where to start with. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean...

Comment: Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum.

Comment: You could find $\tan^{-1}(2\tan(y))$ first and do $y=\tan(x)$ at the end.

Comment: For example, "The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all we will prove the following inequality:

$\color{brown}{\left|\arctan(x)+\arctan\left(\!\dfrac x{2x^2+1}\!\right)\right|<\dfrac\pi2\;\quad\forall\,x\!\in\mathbb R\;.\quad\color{blue}{(1)}}$

Let $\;x\;$ be any real number.

There are three possible cases: $\;x=0\;$ or $\;x>0\;$ or $\;x<0\;.$

*First case:*$\;x=0\;.$

If $\;x=0\;,\;$ then $\;\left|\arctan(x)+\arctan\left(\!\dfrac x{2x^2+1}\!\right)\right|=0<\dfrac\pi2\;.$

*Second case:*$\;x>0\;.$

If $\;x>0\;,\;$ then $\;\arctan(x)\,,\,\arctan\left(\!\dfrac x{2x^2+1}\!\right)\!\in\left]0,\dfrac\pi2\right[\;.$

Since $\;\dfrac x{2x^2+1}<\dfrac1x\;,\;$ it results that

$\tan\left[\arctan\left(\!\dfrac x{2x^2+1}\!\right)\right]=\dfrac x{2x^2+1}<\dfrac1x=\cot\!\big[\!\arctan(x)\big]\;.$

But $\;\cot\!\big[\!\arctan(x)\big]=\tan\!\left[\dfrac\pi2-\arctan(x)\right]\;,\;$ so we get that

$\tan\left[\arctan\left(\!\dfrac x{2x^2+1}\!\right)\right]<\tan\!\left[\dfrac\pi2-\arctan(x)\right]\;.$

Given that the function $\;\arctan\;$ is increasing on the interval $\;\left]0,\dfrac\pi2\right[\;\left(\text{actually it is increasing on}\left]-\dfrac\pi2,\dfrac\pi2\right[\,\right),\,$ from the previous inequality, it follows that

$\arctan\left(\!\dfrac x{2x^2+1}\!\right)<\dfrac\pi2-\arctan(x)\;,$

$\arctan(x)+\arctan\left(\!\dfrac x{2x^2+1}\!\right)<\dfrac\pi2\;.$

On the other hand, both $\;\arctan(x)\;$ and $\;\arctan\left(\!\dfrac x{2x^2+1}\!\right)\;$ are positive , hence the last inequality can be written in the following way:

$\left|\arctan(x)+\arctan\left(\!\dfrac x{2x^2+1}\!\right)\right|<\dfrac\pi2\;.$

*Third case:*$\;x<0\;.$

If $\;x<0\;,\;$ then we proceed by using the oddness of the function $\;\arctan\;$:

$\begin{align}
&\left|\arctan(x)+\arctan\left(\!\dfrac x{2x^2+1}\!\right)\right|=\\
&=\left|-\arctan(-x)-\arctan\left(\!\dfrac{-x}{2(-x)^2+1}\!\right)\right|=\\
&=\left|\arctan(-x)+\arctan\left(\!\dfrac{-x}{2(-x)^2+1}\!\right)\right|<\dfrac\pi2\;,
\end{align}$

indeed $\;-x>0\;$ and we have already proved the inequality in the case of positive real numbers (look at the second case).

Now we will prove that

$\color{brown}{\arctan(2x)=\arctan(x)+\arctan\left(\dfrac x{2x^2+1}\right)\;\quad\forall\,x\!\in\mathbb R\;.}$

$\begin{align}
&\text{Let }\;x\;\text{ be any real number.}\\
&\text{Let }\;\alpha=\arctan(x)\;\text{ and }\;\beta=\arctan\left(\dfrac x{2x^2+1}\right)\;.
\end{align}$

It results that

$\alpha\in\left]-\dfrac\pi2,\dfrac\pi2\right[\;,\;\;\beta\in\left]-\dfrac\pi2,\dfrac\pi2\right[\;,$

$\tan\alpha=x\;,\;\;\tan\beta=\dfrac x{2x^2+1}\;.$

Moreover, from the inequality $\;(1)\;,\;$ it follows that

$\alpha+\beta\in\left]-\dfrac\pi2,\dfrac\pi2\right[.$

By using the addition formula of $\;\tan\;,\;$ we get that

$\tan\left(\alpha+\beta\right)=\dfrac{\tan\alpha+\tan\beta}{1-\tan\alpha\tan\beta}=\dfrac{x+\dfrac x{2x^2+1}}{1-\dfrac{x^2}{2x^2+1}}=2x\;.$

Since the function $\;\tan\;$ is invertible on $\;\left]-\dfrac\pi2,\dfrac\pi2\right[\;$ and $\;\alpha+\beta\in\left]-\dfrac\pi2,\dfrac\pi2\right[\;,\;$ it follows that

$\arctan(2x)=\alpha+\beta\;\;,$

that is

$\arctan(2x)=\arctan(x)+\arctan\left(\dfrac x{2x^2+1}\right)\;.$